# Sudden fall in wifi internet speed in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

My Internet speed speed has gone down suddenly and pages are opening extremely slowly.

I tried searching the Internet but none of the solutions worked.

some information

```
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 10:1f:74:f0:64:f7
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:d4700000-d471ffff memory:d472a000-d472afff ioport:4060(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: 08:11:96:5a:1f:e8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-44-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:48 memory:d4400000-d4401fff
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: This is another comment...  Please delete all comments , scroll down and add your answer in the "answer" box...  **;-)**  Then I will be able to upvote (my other comments deleted already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this adapter does not work well in 802.11n mode. So disabling it improves connection.** sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"** You can also try to disable not all 802.11n, but partially. It can be selected by 11n_disable=2, 11n_disable=4 or 11n_disable=8 instead of 11n_disable=1. You can enable all of them and remove one by one to test which one does the trick. Every new setting overwrites the previous one.